# Why is std::vector so much more popular than std::deque?

Tags: c++, vector, deque

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would I prefer using vector to deque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345152/why-would-i-prefer-using-vector-to-deque)

I am curious why is it that [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is so much more popular than [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). Deque is almost as efficient in lookup, more efficient in insert (without vector::reserve)and allows for inserting/deleting in the front.

Herb Sutter once recommended that [if you want to use vector, just prefer deque](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm) (I am paraphrasing). However in a recent talk on [Writing Modern C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-835T) he again strongly recommends thinking of `std::vector` as a default container. According to the [GOTW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm) I linked earlier, even the standard has similar wording.

Is there a reason for this disparity? Is it just that `vector` is simpler and more well known, or is there a technical reason? Or is it that `vector` is just a cooler name .. ?

Comment: Just my opinion, but generally I don't think we use the front end as much as the back.

Comment: IIRC both Scott Meyers and Bjarne recommend vector as "the default container". Also, afaik, it's the only standard container who's underlying memory model is compatible with C APIs (so I guess that's a plus over deque?)

Comment: More memory efficient, perhaps? Sounds like a linked list would eat a lot of memory. Is `deque` a linked list?

Comment: @chris It is a very rare use I agree

Comment: @Borgleader very good point!

Comment: @JanDvorak - You can think of it as a linked list of vectors (very roughly speaking). Vector stores all elements in 1 block and has to reallocate if your inserts overflow this block. In deque, its stored in several blocks, so if a block overflows, a new block is allocated.

Comment: @KarthikT then `deque` seems like a great data structure.

Comment: @JanDvorak: No, [follow the white rabbit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292332/what-really-is-a-deque-in-stl).

Comment: @MatthieuM. yes this appears to be an exact duplicate, stack overflow needs a better "similar questions" search, I will vote to close this question, thanks for all your views guys!

Comment: @JanDvorak: A `deque` is an "unrolled" linked list. That is, instead of each node holding one element, each node holds some large, but finite number of elements.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Do you know if the Java Deque is implemented similarly?

Comment: Even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139824/vector-or-deque is similar

Comment: @BillyONeal: Not quite. The O(1) access could not be achieved with an unrolled linked list.

Comment: @JanDvorak: No idea, I don't care much about Java ;)

Comment: Also `vector` easily fits into CPU cache and arithmetic operations on vector's elements can easily be vectorized. Doing this with `deque` is not that easy if it all possible

Comment: To be honest, until now I didn't know that a deque offers random access! I always thought it was just a queue you could push and pop from both ends.

Comment: @Matthieu: I don't believe `deque` requires `O(1)` access. But I can't seem to find anything in the standard to conform or deny that.

Comment: @BillyONeal: They do, otherwise they would not have a `operator[]` and `at()` methods which are trademarks of Random Access Containers. *§23.3.3.1/1 A deque is a sequence container that, like a vector (23.3.6), supports random access iterators.*

Comment: @Matthieu: I can't find anything that requires random access iterators to be `O(1)`; only that they be "efficient". Even an unrolled linked list the size of available memory is going to be really fast.

Comment: @BillyONeal: It may be a term of the art (I do not find its definition either). Indirectly, in §25.4.3 Binary Search we get *They are especially appropriate for random access iterators, because these algorithms do a logarithmic number of steps through the data structure.* which is only feasible if `it + n` is O(1).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I can't speak for anybody else, but I can for myself.

When I first read about `std::deque`, I thought it was cool enough that for a while, I treated it not only as the default container, but as nearly the *only* container I used.

Then somebody asked about why, and I expounded at length on its virtues and why it was the best container to use for practically everything, and how it was much more versatile than `std::vector`.

Fortunately, the guy questioning my decision on it was persuasive enough that I did some testing. Testing showed that in nearly every case, `std::deque` was slower than `std::vector` -- often by a substantial factor (e.g., around 2). In fact, of the code I'd written using `std::deque`, just replacing `std::deque` with `std::vector` gave a speedup in all but a handful of cases.

I have used `std::deque` in a few cases since then, but definitely don't treat it as the default any more. The simple fact is that in the usual implementation it's noticeably slower than `std::vector` for *most* purposes.

I should add, however, that I'm reasonably certain that with the right implementation, it *could* be nearly equivalent to `std::vector` in virtually all cases. Most use a representation that's undoubtedly great from an asymptotic viewpoint, but doesn't work out quite so wonderfully (for many purposes) in the real world.

Comment: +1: Great answer! Nice that you actually put it to the test.

Answer (score 14):

`std::vector` is very well understood, simple and is compatible with C (both in terms of the memory layout, and in terms of using pointers as iterators).

For some operations it is also more efficient than `std::deque`. Accessing elements by index is one example.

For a given task, it makes sense to use the simplest container that does the job well. In many cases that simplest container is `std::vector`.

Comment: +1 For the Occam's razor answer.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from `std::vector` being the most commonly known container class, it also has several advantages over `std::deque`, namely:

- A typical `std::deque` requires an additional indirection to access the elments unlike as in case of `std::vector`.
- Iterators in case of `std::deque` must be smart pointers and not pointers as in case of `std::vector`.
- Elements of an `std::vector` are guaranteed to be contiguous and hence it is compatible with c-style functions which take arrays as parameters.
- `std::deque` provide no support to control the capacity and the moment of reallocation.

Especially, the last point is noteworthy.

Comment: `Iterators in case of std::deque must be smart pointers and not pointers as in case of std::vector.` <-- Erm, this doesn't make any sense. Iterators aren't smart pointers.

Comment: @BillyONeal: In a semantic senses, the iterator for `std::vector` does not need to be smart since elements are guaranteed to be contiguous. While in case of `std::deque` the iterator implementation has to be smart enough to jump to the next block and detect the next element. Ofcourse, standard does not say anything about implementation of the iterator class, but that is how things would usually be.

Comment: Possible -- but I don't see why that affects *users* of the library. A conformant C++ implementation has to provide both `vector` and `deque` to the user -- implementation complexities are up to the implementation. I don't think users care about such things. (It should also be noted that at least one popular compiler (MSVC++) always uses real objects for iterator types anyway, not pointers)

Answer (score 5):

People use std::vector over std::deque for a simple reason. They interface with a lot of C libraries and they have [functions](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_recv.html) with parameters which require a pointer to contiguous storage, which std::deque doesn't (can't) guarantee.

Another reason is when you build code according to std::deque and your requirements change so that you have to support contiguous access, you will have a bit of refactoring to do.

I am compelled to mention that there are [libraries](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBVector.md) out there whose authors claim to have created more efficient vector implementations in order to overcome inefficiencies when [capacity](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/vector.html#idx1328) is increased.

Answer (score 5):

The structure of `std::deque` is a bit more complex which makes naive iteration quite a bit more expensive than `std::vector`. The insertions into `std::vector` with its reallocations tend not to be big problem, especially when using `reserve()` and only appending to the end. Also, there are easier to understand invalidation rules for `std::vector` although it is actually an advantage of `std::deque` that objects stay put when inserting/removing only at either end (note that `std::deque` iterators get invalidate upon each insertion, independent of where the insertion happens). Another plus for `std:vector` is the guarantee that the values are contiguous in memory causing it to make fewer memory allocations.

I guess, I would recommend use of `std::deque` algorithms were consistently optimized to use segmented sequences (I'm not aware that any standard C++ library does this optimization) and users were accessing sequences consistently using algorithms (as far as I can tell, only a tiny fraction of users considers the option to use algorithms). Otherwise I would suspect that `std::deque` is the better option with respect to performance only if you take advantage of its specific properties (e.g., that objects stay put and that you can insert/remove at the end). It is worth profiling the two alternatives, though.

Comment: +1 -- but I wouldn't say that vector has much advantage over deque for memory allocation count. Sure, deque might allocate a larger number; but usually the allocations made by deque are large enough compared to the size of the objects in question that it's almost a non-issue.

Comment: The number of allocations clearly don't matter for small instances. For large instances, `std::vector` makes `O(log(c.size()))` allocations while `std::deque` makes `O(c.size())` allocations. Of course, it may have a better chance to distribute its multiple blocks rather than the one big chunk...

Comment: Yes, but I don't think at the scales we are talking that asymptotic are useful here. Even one of these structures the size of physical memory are peanuts in comparison to actually filling any such structure with data and performing useful work with said data. (That is, I don't think `n` ever becomes large enough on real hardware) The fragmentation problem of having to support a single huge memory block seems like the bigger deal when `n` gets large, and that's an advantage to `deque`.